# Check column is NULL from PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How script php can check
If there is an empty column in my database
in Table the_ad Where column image_link
For now my  script can not check if there is an empty column
What did I do wrong
Here is my full code

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("test",$dbhandle) 
or die("Could not select test");

//fetch tha data from the database
$result_image_link = mysql_query("SELECT image_link FROM test. the_ad");
while ($row_image = mysql_fetch_array($result_image_link)) {
if (empty($result_image_link)) {
    echo "no image_link";
}
else
if (isset($result_image_link)) {
echo "PIC=".$row_image{'image_link'}."<br>";
}
}
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

I see the list of column likethis

- 1. PIC=
  2. PIC=
  3. PIC=pic3.jpg
  4. PIC=pic4.jpg
  5. PIC=pic5.jpg
  6. PIC=pic6.jpg
  7. PIC=pic7.jpg

Why column one and two Not show the message

Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: ```SELECT image_link FROM test.the_ad WHERE image_link<>'' AND image_link IS NOT NULL```

Answer (score 2):

You can add SQL statement `` WHERE `image` != '' ``

```
$result_image_link = mysql_query("
     SELECT `image` 
     FROM `table` 
     WHERE `image` != ''
");

while($row_image = mysql_fetch_array($result_image_link))
{
    echo "PIC=" . $row_image['image'] . "<br/>";
}
```

OR

```
while ($row_image = mysql_fetch_array($result_image_link)) 
{
    echo (isset($row_image['image']) AND $row_image['image'] != '')
        ? "PIC=" . $row_image['image'] . "<br/>" 
        : 'no picture <br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query: `SELECT image_link FROM test WHERE image_link != NULL`

Your check is concerning the whole amount of results. Only if there are no results returned from your query, the `empty` function will return false. You can use the query above or change your if statement to this `!empty($row_image['image_link'])`.

Comment: +1. I think its better to change the query itself rather than getting the values not needed (and then checking for them) even if they are NULL values. This approach may be faster too.

Comment: If course changing the query will be better, but when you want to show a page with (for example) a list of users with their profile image (if existing), the other approach will be more useful.

Comment: I see what you are saying. This approach could be combined with the updated query when say you want to display a default image if no image exists. So in OP's case, you need a php check in addition to filtering at MySQL level.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use SQL operators `IS NULL` if you set your DB columns default value as NULL.

Hope this helps.